How to display code usaged in storybook UI?
I have an Angular storybook file for the FooComponent.
In the storybook UI, I can't seem to find the code snippet for <foo />. How can I resolve this?
Is there a configuration to display the used code? I can't find that in the storybook docs or any storybook examples in github.
const meta: Meta<FooComponent> = {
  component: FooComponent,
  title: 'FooComponent',
};

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<FooComponent>;

export const Primary: Story = {
  args: { ... },
};

In main.ts:
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/angular';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-interactions', 'storybook-addon-angular-router'],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/angular',
    options: { },
  },
};

export default config;

// To customize your webpack configuration you can use the webpackFinal field.
// Check https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config
// and https://nx.dev/recipes/storybook/custom-builder-configs


This documentation may be helpful for you https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-docs/autodocs

By default, Storybook offers zero-config support for documentation and automatically sets up a documentation page for each story enabled via the tags configuration property.

So if you want documentation with code snippets to be displayed for your story you need to add the autodocs tag to it.
// Button.stories.ts|tsx

const meta: Meta<typeof Button> = {
  component: Button,
  // Enables auto-generated documentation for the component story
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
  },
};

However, if you want documentation to be added automatically to all of your stories, you need to change the docs configuration accordingly
// .storybook/main.ts

// Replace your-framework with the framework you are using (e.g., react-webpack5, vue3-vite)
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/your-framework';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  framework: '@storybook/your-framework',
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  docs: {
    // See the table below for the list of supported options
    autodocs: true,
    defaultName: 'Documentation',
  },
};

Please, note that this configuration is applicable for Storybook v8. Please, let me know if you have another version of Storybook, and I try to help you with that.
